# How to isolate partitions based on a column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, partition

I am looking to perform isolated work within a single partition of a Spark dataframe. I want to iterate over rows within a single partition without any other partition contents interacting.

`repartition("column")` will hash the column value, then modulo them into the default number of partitions (`spark.default.parallelism` being 200). This may co-mingle per column partition contents into one partition in Spark.

An example: 10 rows where I want to iterate over records within a single `grouping` in isolation (I purposefully `repartition(n, col)` such that `n` is less than or equal to the number of groups, but this illustrates the point):

```
val jsonString   = """[{"eventId": 1, "grouping": 1, "debug": "foo"},
{"eventId": 2, "grouping": 1, "debug": "foo"},
{"eventId": 3, "grouping": 1, "debug": "foo"},
{"eventId": 4, "grouping": 2, "debug": "foo"},
{"eventId": 5, "grouping": 2, "debug": "foo"},
{"eventId": 6, "grouping": 2, "debug": "foo"},
{"eventId": 7, "grouping": 2, "debug": "foo"},
{"eventId": 8, "grouping": 3, "debug": "foo"},
{"eventId": 9, "grouping": 3, "debug": "foo"},
{"eventId": 10, "grouping": 3, "debug": "foo"}]"""

val df = spark.read.json(Seq(jsonString).toDS)
spark.createDataFrame(df.repartition(col("grouping")).rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex((i,itr) => {itr.map(row => {Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq.updated(0, "test"))}) }), df.schema).show

val result = spark.createDataFrame(df.repartition(df.select("grouping").distinct.count.toInt, col("grouping"))
  .rdd
  .mapPartitionsWithIndex((i,itr) => {
    val visitor = new AtomicLong()
    itr.map(row => {
      val debugIndex = row.fieldIndex("debug")
      val groupingIndex = row.fieldIndex("grouping")
      Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq.updated(debugIndex, s"Grouping: ${row.get(groupingIndex)}, Partition Index: ${i}}. Visitor: ${visitor.getAndIncrement()}"))
    }) 
  }), df.schema)

result
.sort("grouping")
.show(false)
+--------------------------------------------+-------+--------+
|debug                                       |eventId|grouping|
+--------------------------------------------+-------+--------+
|Grouping: 1, Partition Index: 2}. Visitor: 1|2      |1       |
|Grouping: 1, Partition Index: 2}. Visitor: 0|1      |1       |
|Grouping: 1, Partition Index: 2}. Visitor: 2|3      |1       |
|Grouping: 2, Partition Index: 2}. Visitor: 3|4      |2       |
|Grouping: 2, Partition Index: 2}. Visitor: 4|5      |2       |
|Grouping: 2, Partition Index: 2}. Visitor: 5|6      |2       |
|Grouping: 2, Partition Index: 2}. Visitor: 6|7      |2       |
|Grouping: 3, Partition Index: 0}. Visitor: 0|8      |3       |
|Grouping: 3, Partition Index: 0}. Visitor: 1|9      |3       |
|Grouping: 3, Partition Index: 0}. Visitor: 2|10     |3       |
+--------------------------------------------+-------+--------+
```

Though I `repartition` into three partitions based on my `grouping` column, two of these groups end up in one partition. Thus when I `mapPartitions` any iteration is performed over multiple `grouping`s data.

How can I effectively isolate subsets of my dataframe based on a column name, and process/iterate over rows in isolation? Do I need to reverse engineer and hack my partition column such that no two hashes fall into the same modulo partition number? Or must I account for more than one group falling into a single partition?

This too seems like a performance impactor if I think I'm splitting my data into n partitions, but I might have partition naming collisions where more than one subset ends up in one partition, then my planning and sizing of partition splits is for naught.

Comment: Why do you need to isolate partitions by column? 
Just for the iteration by key? or store by key?

Comment: Iteration by key, where I need to track some state specific to the partition, and only that partition